# Android material 3 Two FABs in a skaffold block one below the other

Tags: android

Good afternoon!
I have a screen like this, how do I place another FAB exactly under the FAB (button add) to animate its appearance under the conditions I set

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class, ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
    fun MainAppScreen() {
    val tabs = listOf(TabItem.PurchaseItems, TabItem.ToDoItems)
    val pagerState = PagerState()
    //val rememberCoroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    Scaffold(
        topBar = { TopBar() },
        floatingActionButton = {
            FloatingActionButton(                --------- button add
                onClick = { /* ... */ },
            ) {
                Icon(Icons.Default.Add,"")
            }
        },
        floatingActionButtonPosition = FabPosition.End
    ) { padding ->
        Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(padding)) {
            Tabs(tabs = tabs, pagerState = pagerState)
            TabsContent(tabs = tabs, pagerState = pagerState)
        }
        FloatingActionButton(    ------- эта кнопка должна быть под кнопкой button add
            onClick = { /*TODO*/ },
            modifier = Modifier
        ) {
            Icon(Icons.Default.Delete,"")
        }
    }
}
```

i tried

```
FloatingActionButton(    
            onClick = { /*TODO*/ },
            modifier = Modifier.absolutePadding(x.dp, y.dp, z.dp,f.dp)
        ) {
            Icon(Icons.Default.Delete,"")
        }
```

but i'm not sure if it's the right solution